# Close Dialog to free up memory

Tags: java, android, memory, dialog

I wonder, how to free up memory after dismiss a dialog.

I log the memory which the app uses. And the memory increases and increases when i start a few Dialogs. But when I dismiss them, the used memory does not shrink. It gets more and more when I open new Dialogs.

So the question is:
Is there a way to remove a dialog completly?

I tried removeDialog, but this method is deprecated now.
I also set the Dialogs to null after dismiss.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it really a problem? The Android OS runs it own garbage collector, so I don't think it should bother you, unless the app crashes.

Comment: Do your dialogs involve images? If so look up the Bitmap.recycle method

Comment: some images are loaded yes. The used memory increases like 30 mb for 3 dialoges. but the images are just 30 kb.

Comment: does anyone know an answer?`